# Validate textfield using Reactive Cocoa swift

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-5

I am trying to validate `UITextField` if it has greater than 3 characters it should return true else return false. I tried using the below code but it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

```
 let validUserNameSignal = self.nameTextField.reactive.trigger(for: .valueChanged).observeValues {
        value in


    }.map { (value) in

        String(describing: value).characters.count > 3 ? true:false

    }
    print("user name valid result is \(validUserNameSignal)")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how the code should look.

```
let validUserNameSignal =
        self.nameTextField
            .reactive
            .continuousTextValues
            .skipNil()
            .map { $0.characters.count > 3 }

validUserNameSignal.observeValues { value in
    print("user name valid result is \(value)")
}
```

Comment: works great.when i combine 2 signals it returns tuple. `let validUserNameSignal =
            self.nameTextField
                .reactive
                .continuousTextValues
                .skipNil()
                .map({ $0.characters.count > 3 }
        )
        let pwdPasswordFieldSignal = self.pwdtextField.reactive.continuousTextValues.skipNil().map( {$0.characters.count > 3})
        let formValidation =  validUserNameSignal.combineLatest(with: pwdPasswordFieldSignal)
        formValidation.observeValues { value in
            print(\(value)")
        }` Is it ok?

Comment: Yes that's what happens when you combine two signals.

Comment: So, i should test all tuple values to determine the result?Or is there other way?

Comment: There's another way but if you ask a new question I can answer much more thoroughly, I can't format my code in these comments.